# end kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exit code=0x00007f00

Tags: kernel, init, kill

during the update to version 16.04.3 there was a power failure and now, even when I boot from recovery mode, I run into this error ([photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nftX3.jpg)).
I can run Ubuntu from the USB-stick, but I am not offered an option to repair my operating system, and I also don't have access to my files. I already tried boot-repair, but that didn't solve the problem. Given your comment I tried to install Nautilus, but this runs into the following error: ([photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt3P8.png)).

Comment: That second picture, are you accessing it from a live environment or no?  Becuase if you are, you might need to be running `nautilus` from `pkexec` so that it gives you superuser access to files and directories (which you need to access other users' home folders on any other Linux drive, if the user id doesn't match up proper)

Comment: Yes I would be installing Nautilus in the live environment,but this doesn't seem to work easily. I added photo 2 in the original post.

Comment: I was able to start the system rescue from a CD. The command line in the terminal reads `root@sysresccd / root %`, but I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: Why are you using `sudo -H`?  Nautilus is already installed - you just need to execute it with `pkexec nautilus` after hitting alt+f2.

Comment: this gives:
`ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ pkexec nautilus
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(nautilus:7882): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: `